# Microsoft Access Deadlocks on SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ms-access, odbc

We are experiencing some problems with SQL Deadlocks when connecting via MS Access.

Is there any way to debug this kind of error. I'm not really a SQL expert (Sorry for that).

This is the exact error I get:

> [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Transaction (Proces ID 189) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction. (#1205).

We have a SQL Server 2008R2 environment.

Answer (score 0):

There are three things you can try:

1. Add a new column with the data type "timestamp" in every table. That is automatically used as a unique key, even if it's not set as a key.
2. Set standard values for every "bit" column. Access can't read NULL in bit values and tries to set it to false on it's own and that causes an error.
3. Set a primary key in every table. Make sure it is unique.

These rules apply only for tables and views which are connected to your Access DB. Reconnect the tables after you made the changes.